# Jest Unit test cases for conditional route render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

How to write jest unit test case for below line

```
<Route
      exact
      path="/control"
      render={() => array && <Redirect to={`/control/1`} />}
 />
```

Comment: what you want to test ?

Comment: I want to know how to test such conditional rendering statements as above(line 4)?